# Sending emails without Mailserver

Tags: email, raspberry-pi, server

I would like to know if there is a way how I can send e-mails with preferabel `php` or `JS` without needing an actual mail server. I am pretty sure it won't work, but have any of you an idea how there could be a way?

Comment: You can send email via gmail. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-the-gmail-smtp-server-from-a-php-page

Answer (score 0):

You can send mail with a lot of services, I believe they are called 'exchange' mail services. Gmail, outlook (or live, hotmail) are examples of these services. Google is full of examples :-)